# What are some safe, healthy treats for my turtle?

Tags: diet, turtles, treats

I want to spoil my yellow-bellied slider a little bit, but I don't know what to provide as treats to break up the regular diet of pellets.

I know that they are omnivores, and her previous owner said that she occasionally got fish, which also provided some extra exercise. I was thinking of going that route, but I have no idea what type of fish to purchase. Also, what kinds of vegetables do they eat? Do they eat crickets?

What kinds of fish, bugs, and vegetables can I offer my pet turtle to make her happy? What kinds should I avoid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turtles love to snack on all the things you've suggested, fish, crayfish, insects, vegetables.

**Meat**

Fresh water turtles will happily feed on insects, spiders, fish, crayfish, earthworms and meal worms. A regular [live fish](http://www.allturtles.com/turtle-food-facts/) as a treat is a good idea. Preferably the type of small (or young) fish that the turtle would naturally encounter. In this case freshwater fish.

The Australian Freshwater Turtles gives a comprehensive list (1) of fish suitable to feed fresh water turtles.

> Sword Tails (Xiphophorous hellerii)
>   Mollies (Poecilia sphenops)
>   Platys (Xiphophorus maculatus)
>   Common Guppies (Poecilia reticulata)
>   Neon Tetras (Paracheirodon innesi)
>   Gold Barb (Puntius sachsii)
>   Flat-headed gudgeon (Philypnodon grandiceps)
>   Carp Gudgeons (Hypseleotris spp)
>   Gambusia (Gambusia affinis)

(this list is compiled from The Australian Freshwater Turtle (1))

**Plants**

[The World Chelonian Trust](http://www.chelonia.org/) has some extensive information for nutrition for turtles (and tortoises) (2), I have created a brief summary:

The vegetables and plants that are well recommended for providing good nutrition for your turtle  are: chicory, raw-collards <sub>**I**</sub>, dandelion, duckweed, endive, grape leaves, kale <sub>**I**</sub>, kelp, prickly pear fruit and pads, turnip greens and watercress.

Iceberg lettuce has no nutritional value for turtles.
 <sub>**I**</sub> High consumption of cabbage, broccoli, kale, collards and the like can lead to thyroid problems (this will not always be a problem for turtles, but can be).

This post [How can one care for a small snapping turtle?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/753/how-can-one-care-for-a-small-snapping-turtle/838#838) also gives good feeding tips for turtles, that would be helpful for your yellow-bellied slider.

---

References:

- (1) [Australian Freshwater Turtles](http://www.australianfreshwaterturtles.com.au/forum/showthread.php?6058-Feeder-Fish-for-your-Turtles) australianfreshwaterturtles.com.au
- What Do Turtles Eat [what-do-turtles-eat.info](http://www.what-do-turtles-eat.info/what-do-pet-turtles-eat/)
- (2) [Nutrient Analysis of Replacement Turtle and Tortoise Foods](http://home.earthlink.net/~rednine/nutrient.htm) - Darrell M. Senneke, World Chelonian Trust

Answer (score 0):

I treat my RES with feeder fish like minnows to or goldfish . Petco in my area sells them for 19 cents a piece . I bought her a half dozen and they lasted her a few days because they are fast and she got tired of chasing them lol